# Javascript New Function on string script - Error accessing nested function

Tags: javascript, angular, eval

In angular project and learning to build a feature to run a custom script using the new function method.

I am able to access a custom function within the string. However is there a way to access the nested functions? The reasoning is I intend to have quite a number of functions accessible so it makes sense to pass it through a parent function.

Here is the code + stackblitz. Current I get an error 'nestFunc' undefined. Where nestFunc is the nested function.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bx5kia?file=src/main.ts

```
test() {
    const script = `
    var value = 1 +4;\n
    console.log('value',value);\n
    testFunc('Success');\n
    testFunc().nestFunc2();\n
    console.log("End Script");\n
  `;

    var testFunc = (msg?: string) => {
      console.log('Test Function', msg);
      var nestFunc1 = () => {
        alert('hi');
      };
      var nestFunc2 = () => {
        alert('hi');
      };
    };

    const userFunction = new Function('testFunc', script);
    userFunction(testFunc);
  }
```

Comment: By doing `testFunc().nestFunc()` you're saying that `testFunc()` should return an object `{}` with a `nestFunc` property on it. Your `testFunc` isn't `return`ing anything at the moment, it should be returning an object with a `nestFunc` property that holds the value `nestFunc`

Comment: Nick Parsons is right. I updated your **[stackblitz-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hp6rns?file=src%2Fmain.ts)** accordingly.

Comment: Thanks both for the comments and solution. I guess my only issue is if there were multiple nested functions is it possible to either one? In this case return wouldn't work if I am not mistaken. I've updated my question.

Comment: Disregard, i just checked I just return both functions. Thanks again! if you guys can be bothered put it as response I will mark it as answer